# Assigning variable value from funtion in while loop

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix

I'm trying to assign variable value from text file in bash file.
Code:

```
    while read line
do

    echo $line | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1 
    value=(($line | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1)) 

done < file.dat
```

File.dat looks like this:

`1 10
2 25`

The first line works fine, but second one is causing:
`Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")` - or sometimes done is expected

I tried different combinations but none of them worked.
Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read a value
do
    echo $value
done < file.dat
```